# Converting .py files into .exe

Tags: py2exe

I have downloaded and installed py2exe (windows). I can't run any of the modules like build_exe.py in either IDLE or in Jupyter. In IDLE the error is related to importing the file "runtime.py". In Jupyter, I can't even load the script. It says that the file is "not UTF - 8 encoded."

I have tried changing the working directory to the py2exe folder.

from . import runtime
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

The script should run and create a directory named "Build"

Please help me understand this error conceptually. Is this related to the installation directory I had chosen (C:\anaconda3\site-packages instead of C:\anaconda3)

Comment: Maybe try to use [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/)?

Comment: Thanks for the input! @Elro444
I will definitely try this out, but I am also looking to improve my understanding of packages and relative import. Could you please help me understand this error conceptually?

Comment: Haven't had the opportunity to play around with py2exe, but form [the tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) it doesn't seem like you need to run any modules directly, but rather make a `setup.py` file, and run `python setup.py py2exe`. I might be out of context tho

Comment: the set up part is complete. But there seems to be a problem with importing "runtime". But will probably drop it now. Since I have the IDLE, I don't actually need to convert into executable files. Just wanted to learn it. Thanks for your help though! Appreciate it.